# Eclipse not launching my program correctly upon running

Tags: java, swing, illegalargumentexception

I am creating a 2d game as apart of a youtube tutorial series. I have only just started and have copied it all down to the T. there is currently only one class and I would like to know how to set up eclipse to run it correctly.

I am running on Windows 7 x64

```
package com.zephyrwolf.main;

import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame implements Runnable{

/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

public static final int WIDTH = 360, HEIGHT = 240, SCALE = 2;
public static boolean running = false;
public Thread gameThread;

public synchronized void start() {
    if (running) return;
    running = true;
    gameThread = new Thread(this);
    gameThread.start();
}

public synchronized void stop() {
    if (!running) return;
    running = false;
    try {
        gameThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void run() {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game game = new Game();
    game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));
    game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(WIDTH * SCALE, HEIGHT * SCALE));

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tile RPG");
    frame.setSize(WIDTH * SCALE,  HEIGHT * SCALE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(game);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

this was my attempt to get the program to run.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: adding a window to a container
at java.awt.Container.checkNotAWindow(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at com.zephyrwolf.main.Game.main(Game.java:49)
```

Please message me if you require any new informaiton.

Comment: It's not a problem with Eclipse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Game class extends `JFrame` and then you are trying to separately create a`JFrame` and add your Game instance to it.  Thus the error:

```
adding a window to a container
```

(you can't put a window inside another window).

Try doing all your `setSize`, `setVisible` stuff directly on `game`.

Comment: Cool thanks, but would I please have an example of a working class file please?

Comment: Get rid of this line: JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tile RPG");  and where you've got "frame." instead do "game."

Comment: Thankyou very much, I appriciate you help! ^_^